# How to handle denormalization in B.I data model

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, olap, database-normalization, denormalization

As far as I know, normalization is done to avoid inconsistency in the database.

By normalizing we:

- reduce data redundancy, and
- protect data integrity.

That's why most OLTP databases are in 3NF.

Different databases from OLTP come together in a data warehouse. (DWH, OLAP).  DWHs are denormalized (1FN), and is obvious it has to be like that, because the main table of a DWH has hundreds of columns.

From that DWH we can build several data marts that we would later use for doing analysis with a BI reporting tool (Cognos, QlikView, BO .. )

The problem is that the data model for the BI report is not normalized.

Couldn't that be a problem for redundancy and data integrity for the report?

Comment: Think of a data warehouse as a report rather than as a database. Also, a data warehouse isn't subject to the same kinds of anomalies that the normal forms are concerned with. Usually, a data warehouse has rows inserted, but not updated or deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OLAP systems (such as data warehouses), the key efficiency needs are in querying and data retrieval.

Therefore some of the design considerations are done in order to retrieve the information faster, even if the updates may be longer.

An example for such a model is a [*Star-Schema*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema) on which we denormalize data in a such way that all the data will be stored in a *1-join-hop* distance.

Key elements such as transactions are located at the big table (Facts), with foreign keys pointing at the dimensions.

The dimension themselves are smaller, and may contain not-normalized data. For example an `address` dimension may store street, neighborhood and city data without normalizing it to `3NF`.

[image: Star Schema example]

There are for sure redundancy issues (you don't really have to store `Day_of_Week` per each date row) but it is insignificant (since storage is not a bottleneck in this scenario).

As per integrity - you face it only on updates (F.E. a less-realistic scenario of `country` change per `State_Province` in `Dim_Store`) , and in DWH update is a rare-case, where we allow ourselves to be inefficient.

Moreover - integrity is not enforced by the DB (or normalization) but by design and implementation of the ETL process.

[Read more on Data Warehouses modeling](https://dwbi.org/data-modelling/dw-design)

Comment: But the question here is if that Dimension Tables that we use for the Reports and are not normalizated, Dont represent a problem for the integrity or redundance of the Report ? if not why? a small table not-normalized could have some incongruty.

Comment: Redundancy is consciously  reduced in favour of these key needs. And integrity is not enforced by the DB. It needs to be this way to meet the other goals of reporting speed and understandability. You instead rely on the ETL to maintain consistency, and integrity. Redundancy is only a problem in terms of that integrity and in terms of space needed. The DW prioritises other things. You could have a very good ETL that ensures all the data has high integrity- or bad ETL that doesn't.

Comment: There are for sure redundancy issues (you don't really have to store ``Day_of_Week`` per each ``date`` row) but it is insignificant (since storage is not a bottleneck in this scenario). As per integrity - you face it only on updates (F.E. ``brand`` change per product) , and in DWH update is a rare-case, where we allow ourselves to be inefficient.

Comment: @Dimgold Thanks , could you please add that part to the answer for the validation.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding redundancy: some data warehouse engines like Amazon Redshift allow data compression that is very handy for denormalization. Let's say you have a table of sales events with 100M records and every sale has a city. In OLTP data model, you would have `sales` and `cities` with `city_id` connecting them. In OLAP data model with compression allowed it's much easier to have `sales` table with a text `city` attribute compressed. You'll be able to calculate sales by city without joining tables, and your city values won't occupy much disk space because they will be encoded.

More info about compression is in Amazon docs: [Choosing a Column Compression Type](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Compressing_data_on_disk.html)

Regarding data integrity: you have to design your ETL routines to minimize the possibility of duplicate data and also run scheduled checks for duplicates based on criteria like this:

```
select count(*) from table;
select count(*) from (select distinct <expression> from table);
```

where  is a list of columns which combination should be unique (your artificial primary key).